# macOS Catalina: Shared folders require password to save when not owner

Tags: macos, finder, sharing, catalina

Sorry if this is really simple, I hadn't used shared folders until now.

`User A` & `User B`.

1. I store files to the `Public` folder of `User B`.
2. I then sign in under `User A`.
3. I open a file in the `Public` folder.
4. Make changes.
5. Save.
6. Then I am prompted to enter my user password.

Is there a way to share files and folders that will not require a password to save files?

Sorry if obvious, my search-fu is failing me; or, demonstrating I don't know what I'm doing when it comes to sharing folders.

Thank you.

**Edits and additions**

[image]

Comment: Are there any subdirectories? If so, do you have write access to them?

Comment: I do. I went through get info and applied to all enclosed. With that said, given this is a shared folder, I would have thought it would "just work" - either by the OS changing access or masking it somehow. I also went to edit a php.ini file outside all this, and can't edit it either.

Comment: Have you tried the first rule of troubleshooting: Do a reboot?

Comment: lol - Always makes me think of an IT person I worked with once. The way he said it made it a priceless sentiment. And, yes, I did reboot. Multiple times now, actually. I have a call scheduled with Apple tonight.